# What does the line "NAME = ..." stand in the top-level Makefile of a Linux Kernel for?

Tags: linux, makefile, linux-kernel, embedded-linux

Currently I try to learn something about modifying the Linux kernel. I found out, that the top-level Makefile in the kernel sources has effect on kernel version and I found out that you can add an `EXTRAVERSION` here, in my example it looks like this:

```
VERSION = 3
PATCHLEVEL = 12
SUBLEVEL = 37
EXTRAVERSION = -CUSTOM-0.1
NAME = One Giant Leap for Frogkind
```

I added `-CUSTOM-0.1` to `EXTRAVERSION` by myself and when I boot my kernel I see changes e.g. in `uname -r`, but I was surprised by the `NAME` line. My Question is: What does this variable stand for? The text is senseless and so I wonder if this is just a joke by the developer or if this variable actually has any influence.

I found this kernel in the official git repository of freescale SDK:

http://git.freescale.com/git/cgit.cgi/ppc/sdk/linux.git

Comment: Where did that example come from? The [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/makefiles.txt) doesn't seem to mention any `NAME` variable that I can see.

Comment: @EtanReisner it is freescale SDK: http://git.freescale.com/git/cgit.cgi/ppc/sdk/linux.git/

Comment: You could ask them about it or grep for it in the sources to see if it is used anywhere.

Comment: @EtanReisner Greping for `NAME` will probably be not revealing, however I gonna try that.

Comment: This is not freescale specific - [the vanilla linux kernels also contain it](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Makefile). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Linux_kernel_names. It is essentially the code name of that kernel series.

Comment: @AndreasFester so its just a code name for the different kernels?

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355 Yes. See also http://www.linuxandlife.com/2012/06/weird-names-of-linux-kernels.html

Comment: @AndreasFester That information makes for a good answer to this question. You should probably write it up as one.

Comment: Yes this would be definitively a good answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, this is not freescale specific - the vanilla linux kernels also contain it: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Makefile

It is essentially the **code name** of that kernel series.

See

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Linux_kernel_names for a list of kernel code names which have been used so far
- http://www.linuxandlife.com/2012/06/weird-names-of-linux-kernels.html and http://www.ubuntuvibes.com/2011/11/many-names-of-linux-kernels.html for more information.